# How to update a field in the object within the showMapper

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm creating a contact database area within sonata and I have a 'read' flag on the entity. When the user hits the show action of the entity, I want this read flag to be set to true. I can't see any events within the showMapper in Sonata that allow this.

Anyone managed to do this or know if its even possible?

```
$showMapper
    ->add('name')
    ->add('subject')
    ->add('message')
    ->add('email','email');
```

Although I don't show the read flag, I want this to automatically be set to true when the showMapper is invoked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this, sonata fires events on all different types of admin configurations, one of these events is called 'sonata.admin.event.configure.show' this is fired on edit or show of an admin.

This is perfect for what I needed, so I created a listener to listen for that event then did my entity editing within that.

Only limitation is that its firing on all edit/shows so I need to check within the listener which admin it is and discount it if its not the one I want - would be nice for a way around this.